# Can JFROG Xray scan Spring Boot Executable Jar?

Tags: spring-boot, jfrog-xray

Spring boot executable jar doesn't seem to be scanned by JFROG- Xray. Other jars are scanned. If its is because of some other configuration or scanning period timings, then I will find it.. Couldnt find any details about it. I have seen that Amazon XRAY does it for gradle built apps.

My App Details:
Spring Boot Version: 2.0.3, Maven Compiler Version: 3.8.0
Atlassian Bitbucket and JFROG artifactory and Xray is configured(Just started, Dont have much info on it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, JFROG Xray can scan spring boot executable apps as well. There are some issues at this time. I wil update once its done comepletely.